# MapView - change map center point

Tags: ios

I have this view with a map that covers most of the screen's area.
On top of the map, I have some images, buttons, text boxes. They're located in the top portion of the map, which I'm calling here "useless map", while the bottom part is for actually viewing the map. This is the "useful map".
By default, the map property centerCoordinate is the center with respect to the full map, as seen as the red circle in the image:

[image]

The useful map is marked in green, and I wanted the green circle to be used as a center point.
I can center the map or add a pin, for instance, in that precise point by adding or subtracting from the coordinate's latitude, but the actual value I need to add depends on the zoom level.

Is it possible to change the map center point, or make any changes that can make the map act as if that point (the green circle) is the center?

The purpose of this is that I want to drop a pin at (or move the current pin to) the pseudo-center point (the green one) every time the user drags the map. So to do this, I'd need to get the centerCoordinate (the red one) and then add an offset.

Comment: Is the map static or dynamic based on user location?

Comment: Use setting visible map rect with edge padding. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30224360/4407087 can help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can add layout margins for the map. 
extension MKMapView {
    /*
    * This is to hide the legal link on the map. 
    */

```
public func centerMapWithBottom(bottomPadding: CGFloat) {
    self.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: bottomPadding, right: 0)

}
```

}
This will shift the map center up. Similarly, it can be done for other scenarios as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of showing user location for the map just drop an annotation pin at

```
 MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
 point.coordinate = myCoordinate; //CLLocationCoordinate2D  myCoordinate
 [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
```