# Setting a MapView's center coordinate does not take into account full size of MapView (off-screen portion)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, mkmapview

**The Problem**

I have a view that includes a full-screen MKMapView. The bottom half of the MapView is covered with a TableView that has translucent cells so that the map shows through.

[image: User location annotation blocked by TableView]

When I center on an annotation coordinate, the current location for example, the annotation view is blocked by the TableView.

```
- (void)centerOnCurrentLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(self.locationManager.location.coordinate, 50000, 50000);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
}
```

**Attempted Solution**

I first tried to programmatically shift the map to offset the center, shifting the annotation up. This approach works if I turn off animation, though it's not a simple solution. Nor do I want to turn off animation.

Instead I thought that if I extend the MapView off the top of the screen by the same height as the TableView the center of the MapView would be exactly where I want it. It doesn't work! When I set the center coordinate on the larger MapView the annotation still appears in the center of the screen, not in the center of the larger MapView. It seems like MKMapView is using the view's visible region when calculating its center.

[image: Enlarged MapView]

This is what I would expect to see when I center on current location using the enlarged MapView.

[image: This is what I want to see when I center on current location.]

If only MKMapView had a centerOffset property that allowed you to shift the center by some CGPoint.

Does anybody have a simple, elegant solution to offset a MapView's center?

Comment: Have you tried using  `[self.myMapView setVisibleMapRect:myMapRect edgePadding:mapInset animated:NO]`

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify on my comment, you can use `setVisibleMapRect: edgePadding:` to create the offset you want. You will need to put it in the mapView delegate method `regionDidChangeAnimated:` this will fire anytime the region changes on your map so you need to wrap your code with a flag to know when to apply the offset or it can be applied multiple times.  Here is what you need to do:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated{

    if (!self.mapInsetsSet) {
        self.mapInsetsSet=TRUE;
        [self.myMapView setVisibleMapRect:self.myMapView.visibleMapRect edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 0, 0) animated:YES];
    }

}
```

In the above code, `mapInsetsSet` is just a bool that you can set elsewhere to control when to apply the offset. Also, you will need to adjust the `UIEdgeInsetsMake` to the desired offset.

Comment: I have tried using this but the `visibleMapRect` is the rect of the full map, i.e. thousands of pixels wide and tall. I was expecting it to be the rect of the screen. And with user tracking enabled, implementing this delegate method prevents the map from zooming to the users current location. Any ideas?

Comment: The visibleMapRect is the area currently displayed by the map view. You may have your mapview is a view that goes beyond the bounds of the display frame.